# Difference between class_exists and function_exists?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When using plugin functions in themes, is it best practice to use class_exists or function_exists?

Example :

If i'm using ACF functions in my theme, should i use :

```
if ( class_exists('acf') )
```

or

```
if function_exists('the_field') )
```

Comment: You don't have to worry about duplicate names when the functions are contained within a class. It's a good check for writing independant helper functions to prevent errors from being thrown.

Comment: So you suggest class_exists is better?

Answer (score 2):

For check if function exists you must use **function_exists()** exactly,
**class_exists()** checks if class exists.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

Using class_exists is enough to check if the ACF plugin is active. It is also better to use namespaces.

Comment: Any code examples using namespaces and class_exists?

Comment: Also, i'm referring to the use of class_exists when using plugin functions in a theme not plugin development.